# Creating a Procedure with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

im trying to get a job (ORACLE SHEDULER) done in oracle every week.

The point is to loop through the 'Historico' table every week, and check every 'ID_Academista' that is linked to the 
'Academista' Table. After that it should compare 'Valor_Atual' to see if its > 20 (it comes from the table 'Tecnologia')

If so, it decrements by 1, if not, it stays the same.

To put it in better english:  Every 'Tecnologia' Is a technology, each technology has a individual grade(Valor_Atual)
That will be inside the 'Academista'(student)

[Table Historico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbhXD.png)
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnUmX.jpg)

Here is the code :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE notas
  IS
    contar INTEGER := 0;
    contar2 INTEGER;

BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO contar2 FROM Academista;

  WHILE contar <= contar2 
    LOOP

    SELECT  h.Valor_Atual, h.Valor_Antigo, h.Id_academista FROM  HISTORICO h
  WHERE  h.Id_academista = contar ;


       IF 
           h.Valor_Atual > 20
    THEN
          UPDATE HISTORICO 
             SET Valor_Atual = Valor_Atual + 1
              WHERE h.Id_academista = contar;

          ELSE
              UPDATE HISTORICO 
                SET Valor_Atual = Valor_Atual - 1
                  WHERE h.Id_academista = contar ;   

                  SET contar := contar + 1;

           END IF;   

    END LOOP; 

END;
```

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpuT9.png)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The procedure doens't compile, does the code i wrote makes sense  or am i missing something

Comment: What compilation errors do you get? Remember we can 't compile your code because we don't have your schema, so no dependent objects.

Comment: Although this is obviously wrong: `SET contar := contar + 1;`. The PL/SQL syntax for incrementing is just `contar := contar + 1;`

Comment: Yes, you are rigth that was one of the errors. I edited the question and added an  image of the errors at the end of the code section.

Comment: Please don't post images. Many people work behind firewalls which block access to image sites.

Comment: Ok my bad, i didn't know about that. So the errors are the following: 
Error(13,5): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement - 
Error(18,12): PLS-00201: identifier 'H.VALOR_ATUAL' must be declared
-
And "h.Valor_Atual > 20" gives statement ignored

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. You're missing the into clause. Not sure what additional info we can provide that the error message doesn't.

Comment: @SamM yes you are rigth, I will try to fix the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use selects inside a pl/sql block without a variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE notas
  IS
    contar INTEGER := 0;
    contar2 INTEGER;

    h_var HISTORICO%rowtype;

BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO contar2 FROM Academista;

  WHILE contar <= contar2 
    LOOP

    SELECT  h.* into h_var FROM  HISTORICO h
  WHERE  h.Id_academista = contar ;


       IF 
           h_var.Valor_Atual > 20
    THEN
          UPDATE HISTORICO 
             SET Valor_Atual = Valor_Atual + 1
              WHERE h_var.Id_academista = contar;

          ELSE
              UPDATE HISTORICO 
                SET Valor_Atual = Valor_Atual - 1
                  WHERE h_var.Id_academista = contar ;   

                  SET contar := contar + 1;

           END IF;   

    END LOOP; 

END;
```

Comment: what's %rowtype? I never saw it before

Comment: "h_var HISTORICO%rowtype" means that the variable h_var has the structure of a row of the table HISTORICO so you don't have to create a record to work with in PL/SQL